# Centering ToC title with latex package tocloft

Tags: latex, tableofcontents

In my LaTex paper, I need to produce such a table of contents, list of figures and list of tables, all of which have the title being centered and capitalized, and other special additions (such as inserting lines with words "Chapters", "Figure", and "Table"). My elaborations on this project so far produced this latex code (see below).

However, the only thing that does not work for me is centering the title of the table of contents, which is labelled as one word "Contents." See the picture of the pdf output file below. What should I fix in my code? For my manipulations I used two packages: `titlesec` and `tocloft`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
% Set the page margins as required
\usepackage[left=1.25in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}     % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing % Double space 
\usepackage{endnotes}     % All notes 2b place at a separate section 'Endnotes'
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{acro}         % Acronyms/abbreviations
\include{00-Acronyms}     % List of acronyms, 2b updated
%--> acro manual: https://mirror2.sandyriver.net/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/acro/acro-manual.pdf
% Managing sections
\usepackage{titlesec}     % To modify the section titles
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}} % CHAPTER 1 [New Line] TITLE
\titleformat{\section}[display]            % each chapter has two lines...
  {\normalfont\Large\filcenter}{\MakeUppercase{Chapter~\thesection}}{0pt}{}
% Capitalizing the titles of the respective sections:
\renewcommand{\notesname}{\centering \MakeUppercase{Endnotes}}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centering \MakeUppercase{Contents}}
\renewcommand{\refname}{\centering \MakeUppercase{References}}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\centering \MakeUppercase{List of Illustrations}}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\centering \MakeUppercase{List of Tables}}
\usepackage{tocloft}      % <-- ...to modify ToC, LoF, and LoT
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Large} % ToC = Table of Contents
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill\Large} % LoF = List of Figures
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hfill\Large} % LoT = List of Tables
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hfill}
\usepackage{natbib}       % Bibliography management
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
% My info
\date{October 14th, 2023}

% ----- Start of the document --------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
% All notes to be in the separate section 'Endnotes'
\let\footnote=\endnote

% Table of Contents + making TOC not in bold font
{\let\bfseries\mdseries \tableofcontents} \newpage

% List of Figures/Illustrations
\listoffigures 
\addtocontents{lof}{{~Figure}~\hfill{Page}\par} % <- inserting a line w/"Figure"
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\uppercase{List of Illustrations}}
\newpage

% List of Tables
\listoftables
\addtocontents{lot}{{~Table}~\hfill{Page}\par} % <- inserting a line w/ "Table"
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\uppercase{List of Tables}}
\newpage 

% List of Acronyms/Abbreviations
\printacronyms[pages = {display=all,seq/use=false},
           name  = \uppercase{List of Acronyms}]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\uppercase{List of Acronyms}}

%
% ... some latex code
%

\end{document}
% ----- End of the document ----------------------------------------------------
```

[image]

Comment: x-post https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/698974/36296

Comment: @However voted to migrate: please first check if the question already exists on the target site. This avoids having to close it as duplicate there.